# Continuous linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that $f:(\ell^1,\parallel. \parallel_1)\to \mathbb K$ defined by $f((x_n))=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\vert x_n\vert}{n}$ is continuous linear functional and the norm of $f$ is attained in $\ell^1$.

I have shown that $f$ is linear and continuous as $\vert f((x_n))\vert\leq (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2})^{1/2}\parallel (x_n)\parallel_1$. But how to show that there exists $(x_n)\in \ell^1$ such that $f((x_n))=\parallel f\parallel$? Please help!

Comment: Have you used Cauchy Schwartz inequality?

Comment: Yes...to show continuity

Comment: Then you should have $||(x_n)||_2$ in the inequality. Note that, you have been given $(x_n)\in \ell^{1} $ only.

Comment: Can I say that $\parallel (x_n)\parallel_2\leq \parallel (x_1)\parallel_1$?

Comment: The question is : if we have  $(x_n)\in \ell^1$ then can we say $(x_n)\in \ell^2$?

Comment: Sorry, my question is wrong as pointed out by Martin Argerami

Comment: It is not true that $\|x\|_2\leq\|x\|_1$: think for example $x=(2,0,0,\ldots)$. But as $x\in\ell^1$ implies that its entries are eventually less than $1$, we do have $\ell^1\subset\ell^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Note first that your definition is wrong: if you put absolute value, you don't get a linear functional. It likely should be $x\mapsto\sum_n x_n/n$.

Also, your estimate is too crude. You have
$$
\left|f(x)\right|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}n\right|\leq\sum_n|x_n|=\|x\|,
$$
as $1/n\leq1$ for all $n$.

Finally, the norm is easily attained at $x=(1,0,0,\ldots)$.

---

**Edit:** the above functional is a particular case of functionals of the form 
$$
x\mapsto \sum_n a_nx_n,
$$
where $a\in\ell^\infty$. For such a functional, the norm is $\|a\|_\infty$.

Comment: yeah I am wrong...this should be as you have mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: If the function is defined by $f((x_n))=\sum\limits_{n}(1-\dfrac{1}{n})x_n$, then also $\vert f((x_n))\vert\leq \parallel (x_n)\parallel_1$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Whenever you put weights with absolute value less than $1$, the functional will have norm less than $1$. I will clarify in an edit.